# htaccess rules not behaving as expected

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website and two domains, domain1.com and domain2.com. I would like the website to work under domain1.com exclusively.

The website also has a blog, which used to have the following URL structure: domain1.com/something/article-name, and now needs to have this one: domain1.com/article-name.

I also need the site to work redirect or HTTP request to HTTPS, and all non-www. request to www.

I have added the following rules to my htaccess:

```
#Redirect all domain2 to domain1
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Remove the subdirectory from blog
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^something/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

These rules achieve the behaviors I want in many situations, but it fails in others. These are the most representative examples I've found:

- https://www.domain2.com/url1/ redirects to
  https://www.domain1.com/url1/
- https://www.domain2.com/fr/url1/ does
  not redirect
- https://www.domain2.com/fr/something/article-name/ redirects to
  https://www.domain1.com/fr/article-name/
- https://www.domain2.com/fr/article-name/ does not redirect

So, when there is a redirect, it is always correct, there is never a wrong redirection (that I've found); but sometimes there is no redirection when they should be.

I've been looking at these rules for a while now but for the life of me I can't see anything wrong with them.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I have added the following rules to my htaccess:" - Where exactly? And where is the `.htaccess` file (in the root or `/fr/` directory)? What other rules do you have? Those rules don't match the examples. You say you want to redirect to www and your examples show redirections to www, but your rule explicitly states `domain1.com` only (no-www)? It looks like you may have put the rules in the wrong place and are possibly conflicting with other rules.

Comment: "`https://www.domain2.com/fr/something/url2/` redirects to `https://www.domain1.com/fr/guia-ia-de-traduccion/`" - is `guia-ia-de-traduccion` meant to be `url2` and this is just a typo in the question? But still, the rules you've posted  would not do this (ie. they would not work to remove `something/` from this URL).

Comment: _Aside:_ You must test with 302 (temporary) redirects (and disable caching in the browser). 301 (permanent) redirects are cached persistently by the browser and can make testing very problematic.

Comment: "which used to have the following URL structure: `domain1.com/something/article-name`" - but in your example you are requesting `https://www.domain2.com/fr/something/url2/ ` (`domain2.com`, as opposed to `domain1.com` and there is an `/fr` prefix?)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this @MrWhite ! And sorry for the inconsistencies in my question, I was trying to keep the site anonymous as per the client's request. The .htaccess is in the route of the domain, and the rules I'm using are working on some scenarios, so that gives me confidence I'm putting them in the right place, and that it is the rules themselves that are flawed